# LayoutPanel percentage, what does it actually mean?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a layout panel divided into 20 rows all equally proportioned the same size. 20 rows @ 5% = 100% yet the last row is about 2 times as large as all the other rows. Why is this happening?

```
   // LayoutPanel1
    // 
    this.LayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;
    this.LayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.LayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 4);
    this.LayoutPanel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
    this.LayoutPanel1.Name = "LayoutPanel1";
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowCount = 20;
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5F));
    this.LayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 433);
    this.LayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 4;
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps the first 19 rows have 21 pixels in height each - which makes the last row 34 pixels high? The height of a row must be an integer right? You should change the height of the layout panel to be an exact multiplier of 20 and check if your problem persists. (i.e. 400).

Comment: Resolution is 800*600, is there any simple way to fix this. I hate when a simple feature built in requires me to remake the entire thing.

Comment: If I paste this code inside a Form everything looks fine for me. Can you add the remaining designer code? Are there more objects? Anything inside the table layout?

Comment: Try docking and resizing the form up and down slowly and set a borderstyle for the layout you will see the bottom row grow and shrink. I think nakiya hit the nail on the head that this is an issue of rounding with the integer. I don't think this is even worth solving and I have decided to ignore the extra space as it's never larger than 2 times but if anyone has a simple solution to make the rounding interchangeable. I guess I would be curious how games with scaling would resolve this.